# Opencl Workitems and streaming processors

Tags: cuda, opencl

What is the relation between a workitem and a streaming processor (cuda core)? I read somewhere that the number of workitems SHOULD greatly exceed the number of cores, otherwise, there is no performance improvement. But why is this so? I thought 1 core represents 1 workitem. Can someone help me to understand this?

Answer (score 1):

GPUs and most other hardware tend to do arithmetic much faster than they can access most of their available memory. Having many more work items than you have processors lets the scheduler stagger the memory use, while those work items which have already read their data are using the ALU hardware to do the processing.

[Here is a good page about optimization in opencl.](https://www.mql5.com/en/articles/407) Scroll down to "
2.4. Removing 'Costly' Global GPU Memory Access", where it goes into this concept.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is mainly scheduling - a single core/processor/unit can usually run multiple threads and switch between them to hide memory latency (SMT). So it's generally a good idea for each core to have multiple threads queued up for it.

A thread will usually correspond to at least one work item, although depending on driver and hardware, multiple work-items might be combined into one thread, to make use of SIMD/vector capabilities of a core.